# PHP shell_exec() / exec() not returning all output

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

Running a NodeJS script returning a long JSON string, both shell_exec() and exec() only seem to return the first approx. 72'000 chars (number slightly changes if JSON content changes, maybe due to UTF8 special chars). Are there any limitations I am not aware of?

```
$_exec_out = shell_exec('node run.js 2>&1');
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I run `echo strlen(shell_exec("printf -- '-%0.s' {1..800000} 2>&1")) . PHP_EOL;` it outputs back the 800000 which I told it to repeat the dash character. I've tried it through `php -a` and I've also tried it by saving it to a file e.g. a.php and running it from CLI like `php a.php`. It also worked for me when I served it through Nginx on my local. Note I'm on a Mac. Can you try my code here and see if it works for you? If it does, what if you increase the 800000 number?

Comment: I've tried your code. 800000 works fine, as well as 1000000 and 1100000. If I increase it further to 1150000, it sometimes returns 1150000, sometimes some random number like 1064960 and sometimes 0.